# What should I return from my helper method that is being called in a before filter?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, before-filter

I'm trying to protect certain actions from being accessed by users that aren't authorized.

Here a small example from my controller:

```
class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_admin, :only => [:new, :create, :update, :edit, :destroy]

    #...yada yada yada...
end
```

And in my ApplicationController (because I need to protect those same actions in many controllers) I placed the helper method, so I don't repeat myself.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def require_admin
    ???
  end
  helper_method :current_user
end
```

What should I be returning from my require_admin method in order to:

1. Prevent flow if `current_user` is not admin.
2. Allow regular flow if `current_user` is admin.

Also, do I need to place `require_admin` as a `helper_method`?

I know how to handle the `is admin?` bit, I just need to know what to return from the helper method being invoked by my filter.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to raise a 404 error if someone is trying to access a page they do not have permission to be viewing.

```
  def require_admin!
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound unless authenticate_user! && current_user.is_admin?
  end
```

The above assumes you have an authenticate_user! method which you will have if you are using devise. If you aren't using devise, I'd create one similar to the require admin I showed above with a unless current_user condition.

Add the is_admin? method to your user/admin class

All controllers inherit from application controller so you should not need to make it a helper method.